mysql ibd import error: cannot reset LSNs in table: Data structure corruption
I am using mysql (Ver 8.0.26 for Linux on x86_64) on centos 8.
I have copied *.ibd with *.cfg file from one server to another server as follows:
source server (Server1)

mysql> show create Table  \G
mysql> FLUSH TABLES <table_name> for export
using scp trnsferring (*.ibd, *. cfg) files from source server to destination server

destination server (Server2)

mysql> drop table if exists <table_name>;
mysql> Create the table with the same structure.# paste here
mysql> ALTER TABLE <table_name>  DISCARD TABLESPACE;

in command line

chown mysql:mysql table.*
mv table.*   # in /var/lib/mysql/dir/

destination server (Server2)

mysql>ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE;

When running NO. 9, error occurs:
ERROR 1815 (HY000): Internal error: Cannot reset LSNs in table 'db_name'.'table_name' : Data structure corruption
In log file:
[ERROR] [MY-010211] [Server] Got error 155 when reading table './db_name/table_name'
What is LSNs?
In Server1, mysql works well currently and both servers use same version of OS and mysql.

it seems you are missing the right rights see https://forums.percona.com/t/recover-ibd-cannot-reset-lsns-in-table-data-structure-corruption/3212/2

Did you ever use ALGORITHM=INSTANT to add a column to this table? There was a bug reported about that (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96477). It was supposedly fixed, but there is a report that the bug still exists after it was reported fixed.

I changed owner as mysql in No 7. I didnot using Algorithm=INSTANT.
